# TSP with CP-SAT: How to set certain node-visits at specific time

Tags: python, or-tools, traveling-salesman, cp-sat

I am solving a TSP with CP-SAT as shown in https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/tsp_sat.py, but i have some constraints that i am not able to formulate:

1. I have some "fixed" visits at specific nodes, for example i need to visit node 15 as the fourth visited note. How can i formulate this constraint?
2. Also, i want to visit some nodes before a specific time point, for example i want to visit node 9 at latest as the fith visited node.

I am not sure how to get the time-point of specific nodes to check for those constraints, as the decision variables only state the visits from node i to node j.

I tried implementing a CP-SAT TSP Problem with time stamps like in https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/590, but it is no performing well (~2h for 42 nodes, but i have to serve ~150 nodes in my practical example).

Comment: What parameters did you use ?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that runtime increase could be somewhat expected in your case - since you have additional ordering constraints, your problem is much harder compared to the Google OR example.

Your initial problem is so to say 2D - it just involves distances and connections between cities, while your problem is 3D - you have additional ordering-in-time requirements.

[This link](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/590) defines exactly a 3D problem - connections plus `t` for time. If you want you agent to visit a specific city in a particular time, you would need additional constraint:

```
stops = [10, 15, ...]
for i in range(0, num_cities):
    t = stops[i]
    solver.Add(solver.Sum(x[i,j,t] for j in range(0, num_cities)) == 1)
```

Basically, it tells us that exactly one of inbound arcs to a city `i` must be selected and, thus, we enforce that the city `i` will be visited at this particular timestamp.

I know only just a few ways of improving runtime for such problems:

- Reduce the number of decision variables. Maybe you have some additional knowledge about you problem, so you could set some free variables to a specific values? You timing constraint is one of such restrictions. Maybe there are some longer and unfeasible paths or some patterns, which you could exclude immediately? E.g. **if city `A` is selected, never got to a city `B`**
- Is it possible to split your larger problem in a set of smaller subproblems greedily? Of course, you won't be able to find a global optima, but maybe it's good enough? Other approach could be using **assumptions** - you suggest a solver that the solution might look like something and you would like to test this hypothesis
- Introduce more and more constraints. Again, maybe you have some domain knowledge that excludes some particular cases from a search space? Are there some upper/lower bounds for your constraints?

(Un)fortunately, such problems involves a lot of expertise, luck and intuition, quite often it's more about art and less about science.